# Assertion failure in LLVM with LLVMlite

Tags: python, llvm, llvm-ir, llvmlite

(This happened while doing the fix I found here: [LLVM IR: expose variables to GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53508969/llvm-ir-expose-variables-to-gdb))

I am trying to compile some code written in a custom programming language. It is compiled to LLVM IR, and then compiled to an ELF by clang. However, I was trying to add debugging information to a call:

```python
res = self.builder.call(fn, args)
res.set_metadata('dbg', self.module.add_debug_info('DILocation', {
                'line': i.meta.line,
                'column': i.meta.column,
                'scope': self.subprogram
            }))
```

I got a very nice error: `python: /root/miniconda3/conda-bld/llvmdev_1531160641630/work/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:106: static bool llvm::isa_impl_cl<To, const From*>::doit(const From*) [with To = llvm::DIBasicType; From = llvm::Metadata]: Assertion 'Val && "isa<> used on a null pointer"' failed.` How can I fix this error? I have the latest version of llvmlite: `llvmlite==0.26.0`

Note: this similar code does not generate any errors:

```
res = fncall(self.builder, self.module, fn, args).eval()  
# equivalent to self.builder.call(fn, args, name='called_{0}'.format(fn.name)) but defined in a class
res.set_metadata('dbg', self.module.add_debug_info('DILocation', {
                'line': i.meta.line,
                'column': i.meta.column,
                'scope': self.subprogram
            }))
```

I updated both `llvm-6.0`, `clang-6.0`, and `llvmlite`, and this error still occurs.

Comment: I don't think the c tag belongs here

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It is a problem with the source of LLVM, which (iirc) is in C

Comment: ... and that is c++, very clearly from the assertion msg. There is neither `<...>` nor `::` in C.

Comment: You're correct. I forgot that C++ existed for a minute

Comment: Can you give a short example, using which others can re-produce issue?

Comment: @ChiragPatel An example of what? LLVM IR? It doesn't get emitted due to the error.

Comment: So the code used to reproduce the problem is on the other question? Or how can the question be reduced to [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @CristiFati The relevant code is included here. I included the line that causes the weird error.

Comment: I understand, but the problem can't be reproduced without irrelevant code. So in order to have an *mcve*, that should be included as well.

Comment: @CristiFati I added the stacktrace of `clang` and a link to the IR that causes the segfault.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the code that compiled and ran the IR (via llvmlite.bindings). This fixed the assertion error. However, as I detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54081557/4807393), there is still an issue.